# JSONParser returns Unexpected character () at position 0

Tags: java, json, jsonparser

I'm with problem to parse a JSON. Always that I try do it, the follow was result is returned: Unexpected character () at position 0.

```
public Object execute(HttpRequestBase request){
    DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpResponse response = null;
    Object object = null;

    try {
        response = client.execute(request);
        InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((is)));
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        String output;

        while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
            builder.append(output).append("\n");    
        }

         if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) { 
            object = new JSONParser().parse(builder.toString());
            client.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
        } else {
             LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, builder.toString());
             throw new RuntimeException(builder.toString());
         }

    } catch (IOException | ParseException ex) {
        LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, ex.toString());
    } finally {

    }

    return object;
}
```

PS:

1. My response returns a JSON well formatted;
2. The problem happens when this piece of code is running `object = new JSONParser().parse(builder.toString());`

The is part o my JSON file:

```
    [
   {
      "id":2115,
      "identificacao":"17\/2454634-6",
      "ultima_atualizacao":null
   },
   {
      "id":2251,
      "identificacao":"17\/3052383-2",
      "ultima_atualizacao":"2017-11-21"
   },
   {
      "id":2258,
      "identificacao":"17\/3070024-6",
      "ultima_atualizacao":null
   },
   {
      "id":2257,
      "identificacao":"17\/3070453-5",
      "ultima_atualizacao":null
   }
]
```

Comment: Can you show the contents of `builder` before you parse it?  I don't understand why you're adding a newline but it would help to see this from a debugging perspective.

Comment: Where is the JSON?

Comment: Examine the JSON input, it probably starts with a UTF-8 BOM, which you will need to strip off before parsing.

Comment: @Eric  I did put the JSON in the final of post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably your content has some unprinted special character at beginning. For UTF-8 encoded data this may be a BOM.

Please post start of you content as `byte[]`.

Comment: My problem was with "\\uFEFF" character. : (

Comment: BOM as expected )

Comment: You can add you implementation of InputSteam that will filter first unpainted chars of the response stream.

Answer (score 1):

It is happening because of UTF-8 BOM.
What is **UTF-8 BOM** ?
The UTF-8 BOM is a sequence of bytes (EF BB BF) that allows the reader to identify a file as being encoded in UTF-8.

Normally, the BOM is used to signal the endianness of an encoding, but since endianness is irrelevant to UTF-8, the BOM is unnecessary.

**How to solve the issue ?**
Convert `encoding` of your .json or any file to UTF-8 instead of UTF-8 BOM.
Like this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead of BufferReader

```
Map<String,Object> result 
            = (Map<String,Object>)JSONValue.parse(IOUtils.toString(response.getEntity().getContent(), "utf-8"));
```

You will get your JsonData into Map and simply you can iterate over map.

Comment: you need to import
 import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.JSONValue;

Comment: I was try do it, but the problem was with a BOM. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is with the content-type. Use something like this:

```
HttpEntity content = response.getEntity();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
InputStream is = content.getContent();
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8");
int character;
do {
    character = isr.read();
    if (character >= 0) {
        sb.append((char) character);
    }
} while (character >= 0);
return sb.toString();
```

No need for BufferedReader, InputStreamReader can handle it fine.
Hope it helps!

Comment: I did it like you write, but doesn't work! : ( Thanks fo you help!!

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem!

My JSON was returning a different space character, so I did add it in my code this::

```
String content = builder.toString();
content = content.replaceAll("\\uFEFF", "");
```

This **\uFEFF** was my problem! And in my Dev environment it is not happens, just in production env!